# How to get some unique user id when user clicks my Facebook Ad

Tags: php, facebook, user-tracking

My client uses Facebook Ads that drive users to his website.
When a user clicks an Ad he is taken to a landing page of an survey.
The problem is that the cheaters manipulate the url and use VPN's to switch IP addresses, and we can't determine the real survey people from the fake ones.
The ideal solution would be that facebook passes an unique id via HTTP_REFFERER which they don't.
So is there a way when the user clicks and Ad that he gets an unique id that will be passed to the Landing page that is on our website?

Comment: Why are people going to this much effort to mess with a survey? You could make them log in (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/), or validate their email, or something like that, but Facebook's not going to automatically do this stuff for you.

Comment: People are cheating because in the survey they can get certain amount Gift Cards. Facebook login might be a good suggestion.

Comment: You might consider fulfilling the gift cards via mail. Having to put in a legitimate mailing address to get the prize would be preventative.

Comment: We do that and we even use a 2FA authentication solution and still people are cheating.

Comment: Hi, Divian, I met the same problem you met here. Did you get some solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I only know of two ways to accomplish your task.

First way is to utilize facebook's Leadgen capabilities and have users submit responses to facebook directly. It is possible to export data from facebook Leadgen if your app has appropriate permissions. It is also possible to manually export data from those surveys.

Second, a little less user-friendly option is to require some sort of authentication on your survey website. Make users authenticate with their facebook account in order to access survey.

Other options are going to be susceptible to various forms of fraud.

Comment: We have a 3rd party company and our survey's are on their platform, so the first solution is not good. The second solution would be an option if there isn't an option to get some unique id via HTTP_REFFERER. We thought we can track that silently.

Comment: You can try experimenting with "unique promo codes" option in facebook ads and prevent fraud that way. Just upload thousands of unique codes and force people to submit what they see as a part of survey. It is not ideal, and should be supplemented by silent duplicate lead detection on backend, at least it will make your life a little easier. https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1181893525262443?id=404748470363829